# Remove children from Panel only if are of type T

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, panel

I have a WPF `Panel` (like `Canvas` for example) and I want to remove its `Children` only if these children are of type `T`, for example all of type `Button`.

How can I do this?  Can I use LINQ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use LINQ, this is one way of doing.

```
canvas1.Children.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(b => canvas1.Children.Remove(b));
```

OR you can loop though all the Child elements and if it is button add them to a list and finally remove them. don't remove buttons inside foreach loop.

```
List<Button> toRemove = new List<Button>();
foreach (var o in canvas1.Children)
{
    if (o is Button)
        toRemove.Add((Button)o);
}
for (int i = 0; i < toRemove.Count; i++)
{
    canvas1.Children.Remove(toRemove[i]);
}
```

LINQ way is more readable and simple and less coding.

Comment: Finally, simple and correct. Thanks! Some notes about performance?

Comment: @Nick there will not be performance difference on LINQ and normal, I preferred LINQ way. it is your choice to decide which one you preferred

Comment: Down voter please leave a comment, if there is something wrong here

Answer (score 3):

Just do a type comparison.  The tricky part is modifying a collection while you're looping through it;  I did this by using two for loops:

```
var ToRemove = new List<UIElement>();
Type t = typeof(Button);
for (int i=0 ; i<MyPanel.Children.Count ; i++)
{
     if (MyPanel.Children[i].GetType()) == t)
         ToRemove.Add(MyPanel.Children[i]);
}
for (int i=0 ; i<ToRemove.Length ; i++) MyPanel.Children.Remove(ToRemove[i]);
```

**Edit**

This way is cleaner, looping from the end of the collection, so as to remove items from inside the loop.

```
Type t = typeof(Button);
for (int i=MyPanel.Children.Count-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)
{
     if (MyPanel.Children[i].GetType()) == t)
         MyPanel.Children.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: The for loop that loops from the end of the collection needs to start with `MyPanel.Children.Count - 1`, otherwise you'll get `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 0):

Some LINQ:

```
panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach((b) => b.Parent = null);
```

Sorry for all the mistakes guys.  Correction made and tested.

Comment: -1 panel.Controls? Have you tested? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel

Comment: **-1** `Children.OfType<Button>()` is IEnumerable<Button> not `Button`

Comment: Try again... but please be sure.

Comment: Still wrong. a) `panel1.Control` b) Lazy evaluation (`Select` will not execute null assignment immediately)

Comment: Now, Do you really think that this code is better than old plain foreach loop? (creating a temp list just to be able to iterate on it using `ForEach`)

Comment: Parent is not read only and Panel.Controls does exist - it returns a ControlCollection.

Comment: @L.B: It's a question of preference.  But I agree, it is a bit convulated.

Comment: @davenewza No it is not a preference. OP just asked `Can I use LINQ`. Not `How to do it in LINQ`

Comment: @L.B:  But it really is a question of preference as to whether OP uses LINQ or the plain old loops.  I think it comes down to syntax familiarity and readability.  He wasn't specifically looking for a LINQ-only solution.

Comment: @davenewza [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Winging this off my phone:

```
foreach(object o in MyPanel.Children)
{
    if(o.GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {
        MyPanel.Children.Remove(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work since you cannot remove items from a collection while iterating over it with foreach.

Comment: Ah, When will they make VS for the iPhone so I can test my code first =P